# Reducing size and size on the disk of a file or folder?

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I turned on File history for my laptop to save files to my external 4TB WD My Book drive but now I am running out of the storage space on the external drive and I checked that size and size on the disk of the file history folder on the external hard disk has a difference like 900 GB. How could I reduce the difference of size and size on disk?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to add a tag to your post or to confirm that you are using Windows 10 to allow an edit to add such a tag. If this is not Windows 10, disregard this answer.

According to [ghacks.net](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/07/08/reduce-file-history-size-windows-10/),

> You have two main options to reduce the hard drive space that File
>   History occupies at any given point in time:
>
> ```
> Change the frequency in which copies are saved, and change 
> the time period for keeping saved versions.
> Clean up versions manually.
> ```

For the first option, consider this image, from the above linked site:

[image: file history modification one]

> The second option that you have is to clean up File History versions.
>   This deletes them from the hard drive and frees up space in the
>   process.
>
> Click on "clean up versions" on the advanced settings page to get
>   started.